# Email a HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I am a new to web development. I have a dynamic HTML table generated using jQuery. I want to mail the table on a button click. I was able to read the table using JavaScript but I am struck after that. I don't know how to email this using PHP ( mailto ) function.

Button code:

```
<button name="doModify" onclick="OQ()">Mail</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 function mail_content()    
 {    
   var tableContent = document.getElementById("cartcontent").innerHTML;    
   var mBody = "<html><body><table>" + tableContent + "</table></body></html>";    
   alert(mBody);    
 }
```

How to mail the string that I constructed in Javascript.

Comment: You could go with something like @Annoj suggested.
I would strongly advise you to rebuild the cart and the HTML server-side. The server has to know about the stuff in the cart. It is more secure to let the server regenerate the eMail from the stored data.
There are two reasons to this:
1: A malicious user could add stuff to his cart, before sending the request to get something for free.
2: Your server likely to be misused as spam-relay as it sends everything you feed it as email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button name="doModify" onclick="mail_content()">Mail</button> 
<script>
     function mail_content()    
     {    
       var tableContent = document.getElementById("cartcontent").innerHTML;    
       $.post('mail.php',{content:tablecontent},function(data) {
    });
     }
</script>
```

in mail.php

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "ur subject";
$txt = $_POST['content'];
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ajax in your function and send the content through ajax. And after that use the mail function after reciving the content send via ajax

Answer (score 0):

1. send this string to a php file using ajax, or copy the content to a hidden field of a form and then submit that form using javascript.
2. At that php file, Get the content and send mail using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**mailto:**

```
function mail_content() {
  var tableContent = document.getElementById("cartcontent").innerHTML;
  var mBody = "" + tableContent + "";
  document.location.href = "mailto:test@domain.com?subject=Titel&body=" + mBody;  
}
```

**HTTP-Request without jQuery:**

```
function myHttp(){
    var tableContent = document.getElementById("cartcontent").innerHTML;    
    var mBody = "<html><body><table>" + tableContent + "</table></body></html>";

    var url = "mail.php";
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send('data=' + mBody);
}
```

Comment: The HTTP-Request sends the HTML-Data (client) to a PHP-Script(Server). The PHP-Script gets the HTML-Code with the parameter "data"

Comment: Overlooked something. SRY.

Answer (score 0):

The mail() function only exists in php.  You need to make an ajax request to a php file sending this variable, and make the php file use that variable in the mail() function.